Modbus-tk error:Error reading registers: Response length is invalid 0
I am trying to develop an application that communicate with PLC via modbus-rtu, I am using tkinter for GUI development and modbus-tk for modbus rtu communication. In my application I am getting an error of "Error reading registers: Response length is invalid 0" on regular basis after every few seconds,but I don't get any response error or in that case any kind of error if I use any other application software like Citect SCADA or TellUs SCADA using same computer and same PLC with same USB to RS485 converter cable and other modbus configurations.
I have tried to increase the dely between to communication commands,i.e. read commands and write commands, I have tried to flush the memory also but result is same.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

If you're polling the same sets of registers every cycle, it might be that it's one particular read or write request that is causing the error each time. You could try only reading or only writing the same few registers repeatedly, and see if the error occurs for a particular frame, or just randomly. Are you confident you are not sending a new request until the previous request has returned a response or timed out?
